# Android image size different on pc

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-image

I have an app that takes images with the phone camera and then i send them to a web server.
   The picture that android saves in the phone's images folder, has a different size in KB than the same image copied on my computer, and they both have a different size in KB than the same image that I downloaded from the server (which I then uploaded).
   Can someone please explain to me why is that?

Comment: provide your code of upload and download image

Comment: In other words, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "*The picture that android saves in the phone's images folder has a different size in KB than the same image copied on my computer*" - how do you copy the image to your computer?